# Spring MVC (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am a new bee to Spring MVC and was trying something to make something out of it. but i got trapped at one point when i am trying to test the Controller. It's giving Unsupported Media Type, i have read about it and according to the documentation. i put a expression in my Dispatcher Servlet Context file like this.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

it should automatically initialize the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which i require to pass my object to controller in the form of JSON and i have these libraries in my classpath in the form of maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

so now , i have MVC namespace thing, have the message converter json libraries in classpath but still it's throwing error.this is my test file.

`PersonControllerTest.java`

```
package com.prateekj.controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.prateekj.maker.PersonMaker;
import com.prateekj.model.Person;
import com.prateekj.services.PersonService;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static com.natpryce.makeiteasy.MakeItEasy.a;
import static com.natpryce.makeiteasy.MakeItEasy.make;
import static com.natpryce.makeiteasy.MakeItEasy.with;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.put;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/configuration/Beans.xml")
public class PersonControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private PersonService personService;

  private Person person;

  private Integer DEFAULT_ID = 2;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldAddTheUser() throws Exception {
    person = make(a(PersonMaker.Person, with(PersonMaker.id, (Integer)null)));

    mockMvc.perform(put("/users/add").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(person)))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated());

    verify(personService).savePerson(person);
  }
}
```

`Beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.    springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <jpa:repositories base-package="com.prateekj.repositories"/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.prateekj.services"/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.prateekj.controllers"/>

  <bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="config">
      <bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimpleStringPBEConfig">
        <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor"/>
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:properties/persistence.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>


  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mysql-core"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${com.prateekj.jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${com.prateekj.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${com.prateekj.jdbc.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${com.prateekj.jdbc.password}"/>
  </bean>


</beans>
```

`web.xml`

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">



  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>toDo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:configuration/mvc-dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>toDo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

`mvc-dispatcher-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

`PersonController.java`

```
package com.prateekj.controllers;

import com.prateekj.model.Person;
import com.prateekj.services.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class PersonController {

  private PersonService personService;

  @Autowired
  public PersonController(PersonService personService){
    this.personService = personService;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  public ResponseEntity<Void> addUser(@RequestBody Person person){
    personService.savePerson(person);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

I couldn't understood, what wrong i have done here, Please make a look at the code and tell me what mistake i have made,
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You show a rather complete application including json conversion. Did it work before last modification and if yes what was that modification ? If not, you should try to strip it down to the simples code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, i started to write the code with the repository level and up to service level, it went good and when i come on the controller thing, i had to implement these dispatcher servlet files, web descriptor etc, so you can say this was the big step taken by me to implementing the controller and wiring them with the service level. so you asked about the last modification. Hence, to implements controller was the last modification done by me.

Comment: @NimChimpsky i have update it with the controller code now,

Comment: Simply add your `mvc-dispatcher-config.xml` to `@ContextConfiguration` in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking a number of steps in your configuration files.

In `web.xml`, you never start root application context. You need something like :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

and as you do not use the default `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/configuration/Beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It has nothing to do with your current error, but it should shortly brings you other problems.

You want to use JSON, and correctly declares it in your `pom.xml`. But you forgot to tell spring framework that you needed a JSON converter. => the reason for your `Unsupported Media Type`. You should add something like this to your `web-dispatcher-config.xml`

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

If you are new to Spring MVC, I strongly advice you to follow a tutorial. I simply googled and rapidly found 2 (my current post uses extracts from second) :

- [Getting Started - Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) from spring guides
- [Spring Restful Web Service Example with JSON, Jackson and Client Program](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program) from JounalDev